# Proving a multiplicative group module n is generated in a handy way

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z})^*$ is generated by $5\pmod{23}$

Is there a tactic or theorem that could help me finding the power of $5\pmod{23}$ for each element?

I was thinking about using Euler's theorem or Fermat's Little theorem, but I don't see how they could help me get for example $4\pmod{23}$ as generated by $5\pmod{23}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Bezout's Identity

Comment: @DonThousand Wouldn't that be more suited to show that $5$ generates the additive group $\Bbb Z/23\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, but I think it can be used for both. Clearly, Euler's Theorem is the most useful, but OP is confused by them so.

Comment: Would it help you to know that you are trying to show 5 is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) modulo 23?

Comment: $5^2=25\equiv2\pmod{23}$, so $5^4\equiv4\pmod{23}$

Answer (score 2):

You can check that $5^{11} \ne 1 \pmod{23}$ and $5^{2}\ne 1 \pmod{23}$ using exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: also, if $5^{11} $ were $\equiv1\bmod23$ then $5$ would be a quadratic residue mod $23$, but it's not, as can be shown by quadratic reciprocity